# Is it possible to suppress email notifications when transferring an event registration as an administrator?

Tags: civievent

I noticed that is possible to transfer an event registration from one participant to another - perfect for what I needed at that moment as an administrator.

And it worked perfectly, apart from the fact that - with no warning and certainly no apparent option for me as an admin to affect the behaviour - Civi appeared to fire off two email notifications, one to the old participant and one to the new, alerting them to the change.

As a consequence of this seemingly uncontrollable, and despite the fact that this transfer tool would be really useful for me, I can't use it because I don't want it spitting out email to my participants. How can I turn off the email notifications?

Comment: There is an extension that has a slightly different scope but will allow you (among other features) to block regular CiviCRM-E-Mails for particular events: https://docs.civicrm.org/eventmessages/en/latest/

A bit of a long shot but maybe you could (mis-)use the extension for your purpose?! In any case, test well before using ;)

Answer (score 2):

Civi will send emails to both participants notifying them about the changes. I believe the user should be notified as it would be against their consent if the registration is moved. But in some use cases if the registrations are added by a staff member without sending a notification about the registration then it is okay to not send an email notification. Since Civi won't understand the difference unless there is a flag that would differentiate and restrict allow users from sending.

You may need to implement altermailparams hook and abort sending. Alternatively, you can cancel the current registration manually by updating the participant and creating a new registration with some reference in the source or participant notes field.

HTH

Pradeep